# How to manipulate XIB files programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, view, xib

I'm working on an app dealing with too many **Nib** or **Xib** files. One main *xib* is calling other *xib*s as subviews. I want to manipulate called xib height programmatically according to data size. Till now I only know how to handle a generic view.

Comment: you can use _auto-layout_ (w/ or w/o size classes) for semi-complex view hierarchies or _autoresize-mask_ for simple view hierarchies, or changing the view entirely _programmatically_ (change the constraints or frames) if the build-in rules does not satisfy your visual expectation.

Comment: **hello thank you again for you help** please look at here  [link](http://cl.ly/image/2P0z3D3W0347?_ga=1.188550571.224825468.1436959553)  , but i dont know how  change it frame dynamically or according size of it subviews

Comment: as far as I can tell about that screenshot, you are using autoresize-mask and according to you description, the items have the _default_ settings only with `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`. I presume you have not prepared any of the views for adopting dynamic sizes. can you share the `xib` file with us, maybe?

Comment: @holex here it is http://cl.ly/031J360q311X?_ga=1.132932486.964183108.1437014595

Comment: please, check my the explanation below with a bit more details about the situation you are in.

Comment: Don't change the xib but change the generated view objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

## where you are

after taking a quick look on the [`xib` file](http://cl.ly/031J360q311X?_ga=1.132932486.964183108.1437014595) you have shared, especially its hierarchy and its settings, I can say surely that `xib` file is not prepared to support any dynamic sizes at all.

that simple xib file has about 200 other views, and individually all views has the very default *autoresize-mask* setting; that is the

```
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
```

which means (briefly) all views are **glued** to the top-left corner of its superview and will not change neither their location nor size if its superview does so; as we know that is your problem exactly.

take a look on this screenshot, it is quite talkative (the purple rectangle shows the common default settings of all views here):

[image]

*NOTE: it seems no one really cared about building up the view layer properly for supporting the essential different sized screens, which has been crucial part of iOS development since we have got iPhone5; by now it has become much more crucial as we have iPhone6 and 6+ devices as well.*

---

## where you should head to

you are encouraged to use either *autoresize-mask* or *auto-layout* for setting up your view, but **teaching you about these tools and techniques from scratch is far beyond this answer's purpose**, but I can recommend you to take a look on the advanced *auto-layout* (which is supported since iOS6) to support dynamic screen sizes in your view layer. later, if you feel necessary you can also adopt supporting *size-classes*.

the [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) from Apple can teach you the magic about that, and thousand brilliant tutorials are available on the web from developers.

the [Multiple Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) documentation is also available on Apple's site, and if you need, the related tutorials are also around everywhere on the web.

---

*NOTE: it is hard to give you direct instructions for how you should change your xib file at this point as the final rules, which will be applied for supporting dynamic sizes, depend on your (client's) policy of how you'd like update an individual view's size, what you'd like to see or show on the screen, etc...; therefore unlimited number of variations of possible settings are available which could satisfy your requirement of supporting dynamic sizes.*

Comment: now one more question like we make chnages in view frame using `CGrect rect = frame , frame = rect  ` , what commands can be used for XIB files inside this class and outside other class

Comment: more over we acces views using its outlets but im unable to refer xib to outlet ( which i given you )  what im doing wrong thank you very much

Comment: with auto-layout, you are not working with `frame`s, you are working with _constraints_, and you can create them in _IB_ or even in runtime; if you use _autoresize-mask_ you still can use the `frame` property to change a certain view's position or size, but obviously you need to create a valid _outlet_ for the particular view, and you can access to that view in runtime freely.

Comment: Thanks alot ,,, but xib wont allow me to make it oulet may be due to its attached to class and files owner is free/independent ..so what i can do to make oulet of main xib file (which i provided you ) so it can runtime changeabke PS: i know while using auto-layout i cant make it dynamic or runtime chnageable

Comment: it is quote easy and possible to create individual outlets and connect to their own views in _IB_, the class which has the outlets can be the __Custom Class__ or even the __File's Owner__ as well, both ways work perfectly; but loading the view in runtime might be different for the two possible options.

Comment: look here[Example] (http://cl.ly/image/3a3R3C3c133k?_ga=1.87696536.1463711308.1437127265  )  [link](http://cl.ly/image/1K3Q2j3L1Q21?_ga=1.87696536.1463711308.1437127265)

Comment: the _ExamView_ (which you cannot populate for obvious reason!) is actually the `self` inside the class... you don't need an extra property inside class for itself _(why would you take a risk to create accidentally a strong reference cycle, huh?)_, as the `self` presents a reference to itself in runtime, you only need to create _outlets_ for its subviews and they should be `weak` references rather than `strong` in regular circumstances.

Comment: actually im new to ios development , just trying to make it my profession as well .. thanks alot  you have owed me cuz you helped me a alot no one has till now ...

Comment: actually what im trying to do is i have created button for diffrent subview which expands and collapse and it is required to reduce size of examview cuz it calling as sub view on main WorkView xib (main nib file calling others as a sub views ) , if its height won't reduces as button collapse then there is huge white space on ipad between this and next view , just want to collapse and expands height as button doing , what i can do to make it happen

Comment: there are also many possible solution for that, using the view as is currently  you need to update every other views' frame which depends on this view after collapsing/expanding. that is just extra and unnecessary headache, and is also quite unprofessional solution. it would do the job for you, but it makes the maintenance quite hard in long term. if I were you, I would convert the entire view-hierarchy to _auto-layout_, and set the constraints properly then I would leave iOS to do the job for me automatically.

Comment: yes you are right its totally awefull for me  , please help me cuz i haven't made this app im just refurbishing this quietly taking too much time for me , 1.auto layout on each views?? or subviews ?? cuz when i arranged autolayout app wont scroll down and displays whole contents

Comment: I can't help you efficiently as you are not allowed to share the code – I can only give you guidance and links to the related documentation which might help on you, but obviously it is quite limited what I (or anyone) could do remotely. actually you did not have other choice but update the view-layer with applying _auto_layout_ for everyone's convenience in future. you are the designated developer of the project, actually that ugly task is yours. I'm not jealous, I have seen such chaos before, it is huge changes in structure, and probably no one pays you for this "update". :(

Comment: adding auto layout giving me too much problem right now , like exapnd and collapse button stoppped working and views size won't getting reduce as required , some of frames/views become static , i cant re-write app from scratch cuz i'm not fully professional as like you , making development my life i love to code , all my study till now is my own i havent learned from a teachrs or professionals thats why its quite difficult for me .. now what i can do to make it possible the way i want white space is huge issue tiil now

Comment: Main issue till now 1.White space as i told you before ,

Comment: yes, I know. I have seen that `xib` file... __horrifying.__ setting up the _auto-layout_ properly might be very huge jobs for the application. there is nothing else you can do to avoid to do that. except you'd start patching the current view-hiearchy and create a completely unique solution for solving your current problem temporarily – which may work well or may have full of additional bugs which you need to fix and you would be completely lost in chaos (I suspect you already are). the best way is to resolve the chaos ASAP by using the Apple's recommendations and available tools.

Comment: Main issue till now 1.White space as i told you before , 2. Two Button subviews still wont working ( i know button will be resolve as your suggestion ), 3. Task nib calling subviews like PC ,MR ,SC,CST blah upon only one button is availbe as which i made upon TaskView ( This buuton will collapse and expand above views as well i wont have any idea  how it could be done ) cuz its loaded and manipulated using

Comment: `NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OneView"
                                                  owner:self
                                                options:nil];

OneView* myView = [ nibViews objectAtIndex: 1];`

Comment: any links to these tools lke you reffered me to viewDebugging tool

Comment: I understand your struggle but I still cannot help you to fix your code like this way, even if I really want to, it is impossible. :( you still need to consider to choose one of the possible ways to make your fix happened, as sharing a line of code means nothing in this case, and the issue exists globally in your app's view-layer. you have two options: __1.)__ start fixing it by updating the view-layer, or __2.)__ give the project back to your client with telling them this simple task'd require a huge changes in the app and they need to find someone else who could commit that.